# How can I brutally and mercilessly abort a task in Java?

Tags: java, concurrency

I programmed a sudoku solver in Java for a homework, and I am currently trying to figure out the problematic inputs it can face to make it better. I have generated a few thousand sudoku grids with [David Bau's sudoku generator](http://davidbau.com/archives/2006/09/04/sudoku_generator.html), and now I am running my program against them.

The problem is that while most of them complete in very reasonable times, some of them prove to be problematic and make my algorithm search like crazy until I run out of heap space. So I thought I should offshore the solving job to a secondary thread and run it with a timeout. Right now, I'm using a thread 'pool' of one thread (in the form of an `ExecutorService`) and I'm submitting `Callable`s to it. I then try to get the value with a timeout:

```java
Callable<Long> solveAndReturnTime = new Callable<Long>() { /* snip */ };
Future<Long> time = executor.submit(solveAndReturnTime);
try
{
    long result = time.get(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    System.out.printf("%d millis\n", result);
}
catch (TimeoutException e)
{
    System.err.println("timed out");
    time.cancel(true);
}
```

My problem is that apparently, *one does not simply cancel a `Future` in Java*. `Future<T>.cancel(boolean)` apparently doesn't interrupt the task right away. Because of that, the pool is stuck with carrying an undying task, and the subsequent attempts timeout because they never get a chance to run.

Adding more threads to the pool is not an option because I run on limited cores and if too many tasks obstinately run, the legitimate ones will be unfairly slowed down. I also don't want the overhead of frequently checking if the task was aborted from my main algorithm.

How can I abruptly, mercilessly and brutally terminate a task? I'm open to anything that will let me recover on the main thread.

**EDIT** My algorithm is completely sequential, uses no global object, and contains no lock. As far as I can tell, nothing will go wrong if the task is cancelled at a random moment; and even if it does, it's not production code. I'm ready to walk the dangerous and treacherous walk for this one.

Comment: Why don't you use a profiler and find out why some of these are taking a lot longer?

Comment: @Bedwyr Humphreys, I'm profiling a lot. The problem is very obvious: the search space is extremely large, and the algorithm basically stalls when it makes two or three wrongs decisions early in a row because of the time it then takes to backtrack. I'm gathering puzzles for which this is the case to find out how I can make the search heuristic function better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe my case was 'special' enough to use `Thread.stop`, so here is my solution to the people who believe their case is special enough too. (I would take extreme care using that somewhere it could actually matter, though.)

As mostly everyone points out, there's no clean way to stop a task without having that task check if it should stop itself. I created a class that implements `Runnable` to carry out in such a way that it won't be dramatic if it's killed. The result field (`milliseconds`) is an `AtomicLong` because writes on regular `long` variables are not guaranteed to be atomic.

```java
class SolveTimer implements Runnable
{
    private String buildData;
    private AtomicLong milliseconds = new AtomicLong(-1);

    public SolveTimer(String buildData)
    {
        assert buildData != null;
        this.buildData = buildData;
    }

    public void run()
    {
        long time = System.currentTimeMillis();
        // create the grid, solve the grid
        milliseconds.set(System.currentTimeMillis() - time);
    }

    public long getDuration() throws ContradictionException
    {
        return milliseconds.get();
    }
}
```

My code creates a thread on each iteration and runs a `SolveTimer`. It then attempts to join within 10 seconds. After `join` returns, the main thread calls `getDuration` on the run timer; if it returns -1, then the task is taking too long and the thread is killed.

```
SolveTimer timer = new SolveTimer(buildData);
Thread worker = new Thread(timer);
worker.start();
worker.join(10000);

long result = timer.getDuration();
if (result == -1)
{
    System.err.println("Unable to solve");
    worker.stop();
}
```

It should be noted that this makes worker threads harder to debug: when the thread is suspended by the debugger, it can still be killed by `Thread.stop()`. On my machine, this writes a short error message about `ThreadDeath` in the console and crashes the Java process.

There is a possible race condition where the worker thread completes *exactly* (or right after) `getDuration` is called, and because of that `result` will be `-1` even if the task actually succeeded. However, that's something I can live with: 10 seconds is already far too long, so at that point I don't really care anymore if it's *nearly* good enough.

Answer (score 5):

Just as in any other language methods to mercifully terminate a thread are Deprecated or not recommended. Because such methods may cause deadlocks (a thread being terminated will not release the locks it's holding).

The correct solution to the problem is having an additional check for `Thread.currentThread ().isInterrupted ()` on every iteration of the main cycle in you Callable. So when the thread is being interrupted it would see it and gracefully shut down.

And since it's you code running in another thread it shouldn't be difficult for you to modify it.

Comment: My algorithm is fully sequential, uses no global object, and has no use for locks. Even if there was something I have not considered that could cause a problem, it's not even production code. I'm ready to walk the dangerous path for this one.

Comment: First read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#stop(). Then if you still want it you'll have to discard using ExecutorService and create your own thread instead so that you can stop it. Though I still think you should just add that interruption check in your algorithm.

Comment: As for your edit of "it will be easy to modify the run loop", this is quite inconsiderate of the encapsulation of my algorithm. It has a single entry point that does the whole thing. I'm not really happy with a solution that would require me to add overhead just to make my tests happy.

Comment: I honestly don't see how using while (xxx && !Thread.currentThread ().isInterrupted ()) instead of just while (xxx) for the top level cycle (there's one, isn't it?) is so much of overhead. But in the end the choice is yours and you can try that Thread.stop () for you case.

Comment: No, there's no top level cycle. It's just `Sudoku.solve(Grid)`.

Comment: Is Sudoku your class or a part of a third-party library?

Answer (score 2):

In addition to [Andrei's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8982429/104950) answer, which is correct, you should be aware that doing this work in a thread will not protect your application from running out of memory via an OOM.  If your worker thread consumes the entire heap, the main thread can very well die too.

Comment: Perhaps you should make this into a comment to my question or his answer.

Comment: I think it addresses a point you bring up in your question, so I'll leave it up as an answer - but as I point out in the first sentence, Andrei addresses the main point.

Comment: I ran into this issue with changes to my algorithm, and it turns out that `OutOfMemoryError`s will only affect the thread on which they're thrown, most likely because this error only happens during allocations. The main thread had no problem recovering without any particular action on my end.

Comment: That behavior you observed is circumstantial.  What I'm saying is that you're not protecting yourself from an OOM with this change.